# Insert Databound WinForm Data into a database

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have searched for a few days on the internet how to create a Databinding form that I can use for editing values, but no luck. I would really appreciate if someone can help me out!

Reading values works perfectly, but update/insert does not.

FormLoad:

```
newRow = issueTable.NewRow();
newRow["ID"] = Id;
issueTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", issueTable, "Name");
```

Save:

```
SqlCommandBuilder build = new SqlCommandBuilder(adaptor);
adaptor.InsertCommand = build.GetInsertCommand();
adaptor.Update(issueTable);
```

My problem is that in the SQL table: "ID" get stored, but "Name" stay null. What is strange for me is that if I monitor issueTable.Rows[0]["Name"], it return the value on the Form.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I wanted to Insert and Edit at the same time. I did not realize that if a row is in an Insert state, that it blocks Updates.

Solution:

Load:

```
newRow = issueTable.NewRow();
newRow["ID"] = Id;
issueTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", issueTable, "Name");
newRow.AcceptChanges(); //Remove the Insert State, to accept modifications
isNew = true;
```

Save:

```
if (isNew)
{
    newRow.SetAdded(); //Add the Insert State back
    isNew = false;
}

SqlCommandBuilder build = new SqlCommandBuilder(adaptor);
adaptor.InsertCommand = build.GetInsertCommand();
adaptor.UpdateCommand = build.GetUpdateCommand();
adaptor.Update(issueTable);
```